# Displaying images from Google Sheets as a table in a web site

Tags: image, google-sheets

I've created a Google Spreadsheet with logo images in one column of cells, but when I try to create a table to add into my website the images do not display in the table.

I need them to display so The logos are visible within a webpage? Does anyone know why the images are not displaying in table format, or how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which method did you choose to display images. My solution worked for images embedded with the `IMAGE` function and not showing inside the new spreadsheets, but showing inside the old. I must admit I haven't tested it with embedded documents but it *should* work too:

**SPACE** character is an offending character in the new Google spreadsheets when embedding images using the `IMAGE` function. Replace it with another, 'safe' character like '-' or '_'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this helps, since I don't know what you did/did wrong, but here's a pasted table with images from the new Google Sheets. The only thing of note is that in the pasted table, all images scale to the cell size with aspect ratios retained, ignoring the parameters in the spreadsheet.

```
formula: =IMAGE("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png")
```

copy/pasted into document:

[image: screenshot]

original spreadsheet:

[image: spreadsheet]